# how to generate a private key certificate using keytool

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, keytool

I am trying to generate a certificate with keytool of java 6 with private key any help?

```
1.   Generate private key, public key and keystore to store the keys.



       /usr/local/packages/jdk16/bin/keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -validity 300 -alias sslcert -keystore weblogic.jks

2. Create self signed certificate

    /usr/local/packages/jdk16/bin/keytool -selfcert -keyalg RSA -alias sslcert -keystore weblogic.jks

3.  Export the self signed certificate to a file

$ `/usr/local/packages/jdk16/bin/keytool -export -alias sslcert -rfc -file ohs.crt -keystore weblogic.jks`
      Enter keystore password: 
      Certificate stored in file <ohs.crt>
```

when i try to import that certifate it says

```
Error in installing the server certificate.
 No private key found.
```

Comment: No path issue certificate details are getting displayed when importing but fails at end

Comment: `crt` file cannot contains private key.

Comment: even i tried to wls_os_cert instead of ohs.crt no luck

Comment: crt is certificate in x509 format, without private key. If you need private key, store it in pkcs#8 or pkcs#12 format.

Comment: Any  pointers to do like it?

Comment: Where are you trying to import that certificate?

Comment: I am trying to import in Load balancer called oracle traffic director from weblogic server

Comment: You are mixing up importing the certificate to the client with installing it at the server. The error you are getting is from installing. How and with what command are you installing the server certificate?

Answer (score 1):

The exported certificate does not contain the private key. The private key remains in the keystore. You seem to be using a long-hand way to copy the keystore. Just copy the keystore to the server. In fact it should already be *at* the server, otherwise you have a risk of leaking the private key.